# Finding all combinations of paired numpy arrays via meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array that consists of pairs of values. I'd like to find all combinations of the pairs without tearing them apart. Particularly, I was hoping for a `numpy.meshgrid` solution for this.

Imagine an array constructed like:

```
ab = np.array([[1,10], [2,20], [3,30], [4,40]])
```

Then my desired output is

```
>>> out: ([1,10], [2,20])
         ([1,10], [3,30])
         ([1,10], [4,40])
         ([2,20], [3,30])
         ([2,20], [4,40])
         ([3,30], [4,40])
```

The output can be either a `np.array`, or a `tuple` (I can convert accordingly afterwards). Please notice how duplicates are omitted in my results, neglecting the order of my couples (if `[[1,10], [2,20]]` is already there, I don't want `[[2,20], [1,10]]` in my output). For the real case, `ab` is of size 30,000, so speed is another issue.

That's why I tried meshgrid in the first place.
For the simple case of single values, this is easily done (yet, still with the duplicates):

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(a,a)).T.reshape(-1,2)
>>> out: [[1 1]
          [1 2]
          [1 3]
          [1 4]
          [2 1]
          [...]
          [4 4]]
```

but for my pairs, my attempt of

```
mesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(ab,ab)).T
```

gives me

```
[[[ 1  1]
  [ 1 10]
  [ 1  2]
  [ 1 20]
  [ 1  3]
  [ 1 30]
  [ 1  4]
  [ 1 40]]

 [[10  1]
  [10 10]
  [10  2]
  [10 20]
...    
  [40  3]
  [40 30]
  [40  4]
  [40 40]]]
```

In other words: meshgrid breaks up my pairs. I assume the solution is near, but I couldn't come up with it on my own. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You stated you wanted a `meshgrid` solution - but consider `itertools` as a less verbose, equally fast alternative. You'll want to call [permutations(ab)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to get your desired output.

Comment: @charlesreid1 I believe it would be `combinations` to get the desired result. But actually the solution below (not using `itertools`) is faster (in particular on larger inputs) because converting the `itertools` generator into a `numpy` array is very slow.

Comment: I avoided `itertools` in the first place, because I frequently read that it is outperformed by `meshgrid` in terms of speed. If it was for a task that has to be calculated more often, I would certainly try both and find the faster one. But since this is a one-time-job, I decided to go for Divakar's solution. But thanks to you, too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't think `meshgrid` would work as it creates all possible combinations (not without filtering out later on). To solve it, two approaches could be proposed.

**Approach #1**

We can get the row indices of those pairwise combinations without duplicates and then simply index into rows to get the desired output, like so -

```
In [99]: r,c = np.triu_indices(len(ab),1)

In [100]: np.hstack(( ab[r], ab[c] ))
Out[100]: 
array([[ 1, 10,  2, 20],
       [ 1, 10,  3, 30],
       [ 1, 10,  4, 40],
       [ 2, 20,  3, 30],
       [ 2, 20,  4, 40],
       [ 3, 30,  4, 40]])
```

To get the desired output as a `3D` array, stack along the second axis -

```
In [115]: np.stack(( ab[r], ab[c] ), axis=1)
Out[115]: 
array([[[ 1, 10],
        [ 2, 20]],

       [[ 1, 10],
        [ 3, 30]],

       [[ 1, 10],
        [ 4, 40]],

       [[ 2, 20],
        [ 3, 30]],

       [[ 2, 20],
        [ 4, 40]],

       [[ 3, 30],
        [ 4, 40]]])
```

As function :

```
def pairwise_combs1(ab):
    r,c = np.triu_indices(len(ab),1)
    return np.stack(( ab[r], ab[c] ), axis=1)
```

**Approach #2** Another with `slicing` and `array-initialization` targeting memory efficiency and hence performance -

```
def pairwise_combs2(ab):
    n = len(ab)
    N = n*(n-1)//2
    out = np.empty((N,2,2),dtype=ab.dtype)
    idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum() ))
    start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
    for j,i in enumerate(range(n-1)):
        out[start[j]:stop[j],0] = ab[j]
        out[start[j]:stop[j],1] = ab[j+1:]
    return out
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
In [166]: ab = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,2))

In [167]: %timeit pairwise_combs1(ab)
10 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop

In [168]: %timeit pairwise_combs2(ab)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.25 ms per loop

In [169]: np.allclose(pairwise_combs1(ab), pairwise_combs2(ab))
Out[169]: True
```

Comment: This is fantastically snappy. Just to expand; if the result doesn't *need* to be stored and will instead be iterated over later, then `itertools.combinations(ab, 2)` will be the fastest solution. But converting the `itertools` object to a `numpy ndarray` is not fast if you do need to store it.

Comment: `np.triu_indices` is a fantastic thing. Once again I am surprised about the amount of solutions numpy offers to different problems. Unfortunately I am getting a `MemoryError`. All combinations of 30,000 pairs means 900,000,000 pairs. I might have to work with slices.